# In Relay how should I get from global Id to local Id on client?

Tags: reactjs, relay

On the server `fromGlobalId(id)` is used to get from a relay global Id to the actual Id on the on the object.

At the moment I am doing the same on the client i.e.

`javascript
import { fromGlobalId } from 'graphql-relay'
fromGlobalId(accounts[0].id)`

It gives the correct result:

`Object {type: "Account", id: "0"}`

but should I be importing `graphql-relay` on client is there a way I can do this with just `react-relay`?

Comment: The answer seems accurate, why isn't it accepted?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the object type and id, Perhaps it is better to just pass it back in the GraphQL response?

On the server-side, define in your GraphQL schema:

```
var accountType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Account',
  description: 'An account',
  fields: () => ({
    id: globalIdField('Account'),
    objectType: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'Object type',
    }
    objectId: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'Object ID',
    },
  }),
  interfaces: [nodeInterface],
});
```

On the client-side, just query for objectType, objectId:

```
fragments: {
  account: () => Relay.QL`
    fragments on Account {
      id,
      objectType,
      objectId,
    }
  `
}
```